# Update a state in react redux reducer with nested .map() for nested arrays

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have a reducer case like this:

```
  if (type === "user") {
    const user = users.find((user) => user._id === draggableId);
    const updatedState = newState.map((column) => {
      let tasks = column.tasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === droppableIdEnd) {
          return {
            ...task,
            users: [...task.users, user],
          };
        } else return task;
      });
      let newColumn = {
        ...column,
        tasks: tasks,
      };
      console.log(tasks, newColumn);
      return newColumn;
    });
    console.log(updatedState);
    return updatedState;
  }
```

Now as you can see the nested .map() function adds a new user to a particular task. Then those tasks (array as well) are assigned to a column. The result though is that columns.tasks don't see any users which which were assigned in nested .map() function and in result 'users' is always an empty array.

Here is the result of example iteration of

[console.log(tasks, newColumn)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mILQi.png)

I want to add 'tasks' array to 'columns' which includes 'users' array, but it seems like 'users' are being ignored by 'columns' for no reason. I would be glad for any help in this case.

EDIT: OK so I figured out that after commenting

```
// return updatedState;
```

It console.logs expected behavior. I have to return this state though in order to change it, so... I have no idea what next and why it happens this is totally not to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over `newState` but not storing the result of the map. Therefore the work that `newState.map` did is all lost.

Save hte map result to a variable and then return the updated state.

**Something like this:**

```js
if (type === "user") {
    const user = users.find((user) => user._id === draggableId);
    const updatedState = newState.map((column) => { //<--------- see here.
      let tasks = column.tasks.map((task) => {
        if (task.id === droppableIdEnd) {
          return {
            ...task,
            users: [...task.users, user],
          };
        } else return task;
      });
      console.log(tasks, column);
      return {
        ...column,
        tasks: tasks,
      };
    });
    console.log(updatedState);
    return updatedState;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned it earlier. I've already tried this and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally figured it out it's been a problem with another case in reducer which was called after the one mentioned above. Sorry for bothering all those who tried to figure this out.